# Change polling frequency in socket.io 1.1

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I'm using socket.io 1.1 to access a server behind Amazon elastic load balancer. Because elb doesn't support websocket, polling is the chosen transport.

How do I change the polling frequency to increase the polling interval?

Thanks!

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129391/socket-io-connection-event-fired-on-every-client-heartbeat

Comment: On the surface, yes. But socket.io did a major overhaul since version 1.0 and they did away with those get/set methods that can be used to change polling frequency. I need a v1.x solution.

Comment: `io.set('transports'), io.set('heartbeat interval'), io.set('heartbeat timeout', and io.set('resource') are still supported for backwards compatibility.`


[Source](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#configuration-differences)